# Slick 3.0.0 reuse query code

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0, slick-3.0

I want to reuse code in my app,

for example, have functions like this

```
  def getA1(idUser: Option[Long]) = {
    val q = A1Q.filter(_.idUser === idUser.get)
    Await.result(db.run(q.result), Duration.Inf)
  }

  def getA2[T](idUser: Option[Long]) = {
    val q = A2Q.filter(_.idUser === idUser.get)
    Await.result(db.run(q.result), Duration.Inf)
  }

  def getAn(idUser: Option[Long]) = {
    val q = AnQ.filter(_.idUser === idUser.get)
    Await.result(db.run(q.result), Duration.Inf)
  }
```

A1Q has a type TableQuery

and 'q' has type `Query[TA1Q, TA1Q#TableElementType, scala.Seq]`
tried to use generic for solve current issue, like this

```
 def execQ[T](q: Query[T, T, scala.Seq]) = Await.result(db.run(q.result), Duration.Inf)
```

but types mis much,

How can I generic `Query[TA1Q, TA1Q#TableElementType, scala.Seq]` ? in the correct way and prepare some separated function like

```
  def execQ[T](q: Query[T, T, scala.Seq]) = Await.result(db.run(q.result), Duration.Inf)
```

BR!

Answer (score 0):

You need two type parameters:

First C which is your Entity and therefore the return type of your query.
And second T which is your entities table and therefore extends Table[C].

```
def execQ[C,T <: Table[C]](q: Query[T, C, scala.Seq]) = Await.result(db.run(q.result), Duration.Inf)
```